# How pass Emotion styling through Material UI MenuProps to override paper root classes

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I am using [Material UI for a Select](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/) menu and [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) for styling.

I need to override the root classes (`MuiPaper-root` or `MuiMenu-paper`) of the menu popover once you have clicked on a menu item inside the Select menu.

I have a Select component:

```
<Select
  value={selectValue}
  onChange={handleChange}
  css={styles.select}
  MenuProps={{
    css: { paper: styles.popover },
  }}
>
  {items?.map(({ item, label }) => {
    return (
      <MenuItem
        key={item}
        value={item}
        css={styles.menuItem}
      >
        {label}
      </MenuItem>
    );
  })}
</Select>
```

Inside my styles file I tried below but isn't working?

```
popover: css`
  background-color: red !important; 
`,
```

or this:

```
   popover: css`
     .MuiPaper-root {
       background-color: red !important;
    }
`,
```

Also I tried to use `classes` prop instead of `css` prop:

```
MenuProps={{
 classes: { paper: styles.popover },
}}
```

Then I get this linting:

> (property) paper?: string | undefined Type 'SerializedStyles' is not
> assignable to type 'string'.

Anyone an idea how pass emotion styling through the MenuProps?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is on `MenuProps` declaration. To override `MuiMenu-paper` you should write:

```
<Select
   ...
   MenuProps={{
      classes: {
         paper: classes.menuPaper
      }
   }}
>
...
</Select>
```

Then in style:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  menuPaper: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
}));
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-neumann-5yfxu?file=/src/App.js) a working example.

Comment: thanks but can I do it without makeStyles() and use my own emotion styles?

Comment: You should replace `classes.menuPaper` with `styles.menuPaper` and `import` style sheet. Sorry but I usually use makeStyle with MUI.

Comment: thanks, I already tried that but then I get `(property) paper?: string | undefined
Type 'SerializedStyles' is not assignable to type 'string'..` 
When I inspect the HTML I see: MuiPaper-root MuiMenu-paper You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop).

Comment: Did you find a solution? Doing exactly this at the moment.